# How to get a running springboot applcation's active profiles from the command line?

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, profile, jcmd

How do you get the **active profile** from a running spring boot application from the command-line?

I know about `jcmd` but I could not find anything that references the springboot properties.

Is there another way or am I missing something with `jcmd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own the application, i.e. you have access to the source code and permission to change it, you can enable the `/env` Actuator end-point which should give you the names of the active profiles. You can call this end-point from command line using cURL, for example.

Ref.: [Retrieving the Entire Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#env)

Comment: Yeah we already have that up and running.
Sadly I can't use curl on the container and curling from outside isn't an option either.

Comment: @WesselScholtz Monitoring and management can be made accessible via JMX as well. Ref.: [Monitoring and Management over JMX](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.jmx). Would that be a viable option for you?

Comment: The JMX thing looks interesting!
Turns out that `curl` wasn't available but `wget` was (for some reason). Poking it a bit I managed to get it to do what I wanted!
Thanks for your help anyways @AttilaT